# Write to the same file,on multiple execution of same program in java

Tags: java

I have the following code,
What it does is,it gets the response from http connection and writes it to logs.txt.
When i execute the program the response gets written in txt file,but when i run the same program again it doesn't write response to txt file.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/mkumaru/Desktop/Elastic/elasticsearch/server/logs/logs.txt"));
                try {
                    out.write(response.toString());
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Exception ");
                }
                finally
                {
                    out.close();
                }
```

So what i am expecting is,
In the first execution, logs.txt should be,
response1

In the second execution of same program,
response1
response2

How can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new FileWriter("C:/Users/mkumaru/Desktop/Elastic/elasticsearch/server/logs/logs.txt", true)  //Set true for append mode
                        ); 
writer.newLine();   //Add new line
writer.write(textToAppend);
```

Comment: Now it gets appended to same line.

Comment: i hava added out.newLine(),but still its not writing on the next line

Comment: You have to write new line then append , i updated the answer, kindly have a look